# CSRF cookie not set: POST from Javascript to separate Django project

Tags: django, cookies, cross-domain, csrf, django-csrf

I'm developing two separate django (version 3.1) projects. I keep getting a "403: CSRF cookie not set" error and have no idea what the problem is.

- Project 1 is running on an Apache server & takes POST requests containing JSON data & sends back a JSON response.
- Project 2, running on localhost, sends the POST via Javascript `XMLHttpRequest()` function to Project 1.

[This question seems to be having the same problem as me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5100539/django-csrf-check-failing-with-an-ajax-post-request), but I'm trying to send info between different URL's (more specifically, POST from localhost:8000, eventually url.com, to engine.url.com) and I don't think that user's solution will work for me.

I've tried using the `@csrf_exempt` decorator on Project 1 `views.py`, and it works just fine. However, personally identifying information might be sent between the two, so I want to make sure things are secure. A csrf cookie is best practice if I'm not mistaken, so I have the decorator `@ensure_csrf_cookie` before my view.

I've tried everything I could find online to fix the problem. In Project 1 `settings.py`, I've included `'corsheaders'` in my `INSTALLED_APPS`, `'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware'` in `MIDDLEWARE` and have the following code at the end of the file:

```
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = False
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = False
CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = False

CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
    'http://project.com',
    'https://project.com',
    'http://engine.project.com',
    'https://engine.project.com',
    'localhost:8000',
    'http://localhost:8000',
    '127.0.0.1',
    'http://127.0.0.1',
]

CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = [
    'X-CSRFToken',
    'x-csrftoken',
    'X-CSRFTOKEN',
    'content-type',
]
```

I include a `{% csrf_token %}` in the Project 2 template, but the actual POST request is coming from the Javascript. Pertinent excerpt from the Javascript static file below:

```
function getCookie(name) {
    let cookieValue = null;
    if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
        const cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (let i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            const cookie = cookies[i].trim();
            // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
            if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
                cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return cookieValue;
}

function getPaymentDates(jsonData) {
  const csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');
  jsonData.csrfmiddlewaretoken = csrftoken;
  var sentJsonString = JSON.stringify(jsonData);
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("POST", "http://engine.project.com/app/", false);
  xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRFToken', csrftoken);
  xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  xhr.send(sentJsonString);
  // xhr response should be a json string
  return xhr.response;
}
```

*`getCookie()` is lifted straight from the [csrf django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/csrf/#acquiring-the-token-if-csrf-use-sessions-and-csrf-cookie-httponly-are-false).*

After testing in the console, I know a cookie is obtained, but I get a 403 error before the app can do anything with the data. Again, if I use `@csrf_exempt` then the app works just fine, but if that makes the data vulnerable to malintent, then I want to prevent that.

Am I redundantly calling for a csrf cookie which causes an error? I'm stumped and somewhat new to web development. Happy to provide more code if that aids in answering this question.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:
Set the needed cookie on the document by adding code below on the template before calling getCookie():

```
<script>
   document.cookie = "csrftoken={{ csrf_token }}"
</script>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work. I tried this line in the template, also tried adding to the static file but I'm still getting a 403 error.

Answer (score 1):

@Ruperto is right. You can also try and not set any cookie just a global variable

```
<script>
   var csrftoken="{{ csrf_token | escapejs }}"
</script>
```

and skip the line `const csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');`.

Or you should probably set some additional safety properties to your cookie. eg.

```
document.cookie = "csrftoken={{ csrf_token | escapejs }};SameSite=Strict;Secure"
```

**UPDATE:**
One solution for sending the csrftoken is to set up a csrf middleware. In `settings.py` my middleware looks like this:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    # ...
]
```

Comment: Ruperto's solution didn't work unfortunately. I tried yours but I'm also still getting a 403 error. Question: Do I need to add the @ensure_csrf_cookie at the top of the view that is _sending_ the POST or _receiving_ the POST?

Comment: I usually use csrf middleware. I have updated my answer. I hope it helps.

Comment: this might help too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40616115/django-403-csrf-verification-failed

Comment: @Ruperto thanks, funnily enough I ran into a csrf expiry problem myself today and used your link to fix it. :)

Comment: @Barney you're welcome. 'nice to know it was useful